# Install PHP 7.4 on Ubuntu 18.10

Tags: ubuntu, ubuntu-18.04, php-7.4, php-7.3

We are trying to install PHP 7.4 to Ubuntu 18.10.

We tried all the following commands, but it always shows errors like E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'php7.4'

sudo apt-get install php7.4
sudo apt install php7.4
sudo apt-get install -y php7.4

We also tied to install 7.3 but had the same issue.

[image]

Comment: I was able to solve this issue by following steps I have mentioned in following answer.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/76829352/5969346

Answer (score 0):

How to Install PHP 7.4 on Ubuntu 18.10.

login into your system, and run the following commands:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ondrej/php
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade

#install php7.4 (if not installed) with:
sudo apt-get install php7.4
```

That's it.

Remember to install the necessary modules for your application.

Comment: as i said in my question, i tried this step and it's not working

Comment: This consistently does not work. I have read articles written a month ago. Yet still the same outcome. Can't find php 7.4:
E: Unable to locate package php7.4
E: Couldn't find any package by glob 'php7.4'
E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'php7.4'