# Can't install php7.4-dev on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: php, ubuntu-18.04, apt, php-7.4

Trying to install `php7.4-dev` extension, but I'm getting

```
E: Unable to locate package php7.4-dev
E: Couldn't find any package by glob 'php7.4-dev'
E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'php7.4-dev'
```

When I run `apt show php` it displays the following:

```
Package: php
Version: 1:7.2+60ubuntu1
Priority: optional
Section: php
Source: php-defaults (60ubuntu1)
Origin: Ubuntu
Maintainer: Ubuntu Developers <ubuntu-devel-discuss@lists.ubuntu.com>
Original-Maintainer: Debian PHP Maintainers <pkg-php-maint@lists.alioth.debian.org>
Bugs: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+filebug
Installed-Size: 12.3 kB
Depends: php7.2
Supported: 5y
Download-Size: 3,084 B
APT-Sources: http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/main amd64 Packages
Description: server-side, HTML-embedded scripting language (default)
 PHP (recursive acronym for PHP: Hypertext Preprocessor) is a widely-used
 open source general-purpose scripting language that is especially suited
 for web development and can be embedded into HTML.
 .
 This package is a dependency package, which depends on Ubuntu's default
 PHP version (currently 7.2).
```

I used the following commands to update the repository.

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ondrej/php
sudo apt update
```

After running `apt show php` again, I received the same message as before, and the version remains unchanged, still showing `PHP 7.2`.

However, I consistently encounter the same result every time, and unfortunately, I'm unable to install `php7.4-dev`.

sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ondrej/php
sudo apt update
apt show php

Answer (score 8):

I was facing the same issue somehow `ppa:ondrej/php` is not working on Ubuntu 18.04. As mentioned in [this article](https://computingforgeeks.com/how-to-install-php-on-ubuntu/?expand_article=1) after adding following repositories I was able to install `php7.4`

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:sergey-dryabzhinsky/php74
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:sergey-dryabzhinsky/php7-modules
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:sergey-dryabzhinsky/backports
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:sergey-dryabzhinsky/packages
```

Comment: PHP 7.4 not owrking in Ubuntu 18.04 when using the ppa:ondrej/php repository is because both of these are end of life and the repository maintainer only provides support for PHP and Ubuntu versions that are within support.